# need help in shell script syntax for "for loop and awk"

Tags: shell, for-loop, awk

I am writing shell script to replace a names in database, for this I have users list of current names and new name in .txt file. File format is like below

```
**new name      current name**
abc              pqr
def              stq 
mnd              tdh
```

For this I am writing "for loop" by using `awk` command, where I want it should gives me the value of `$1` i.e. `abc` ,`def`,`mnd` etc.

I have written for loop like below,

```
function ()
{
cd $directory

for i  `cat $filename.txt` |  awk '{print $1}'
do
        j=`grep "$i `cat $filename.txt ` | awk '{print $1'} |awk '{print $2}'"`
        echo  "update table SET username = '$i' WHERE username = '$j;"
done
}
```

But somehow this is not working. can someone help here to write the code in shell script?

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention a database or your environment, but I think you just want something like:

```
awk '{print "update table SET username=" $1 " where username=" $2 ";"}' filename.txt| someSQLshell
```

**Sample Output**

```
update table SET username=newboy where username=oldboy;
update table SET username=newemployee where username=badboy;
```

**Test Input**

```
newboy oldboy    567    q
newemployee badboy    190    r
```

---

I don't know `mysql` but I believe you can pipe commands into it, so:

```
awk '{print "update table SET username=" $1 " where username=" $2 ";"}' filename.txt | mysql -h HOST -u USER -p PASSWORD DBNAME
```

---

This may work too, but is less efficient:

```
awk '{print "mysql -u user -p pass -e \"update table set username=" $1 " where username=" $2 "\""}' filename.txt
```

**Sample Output**

```
mysql -u user -p pass -e "update table set username=newboy where username=oldboy"
mysql -u user -p pass -e "update table set username=newemployee where username=badboy"
```

and if that looks correct, you could pipe it to `bash`:

```
awk '{...}' | bash
```

---

If you really, really want to use `bash` and a `for` loop, you could do it something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat filename.txt | while read new old _ ; do
   echo "update table SET username=$new where username=$old;"
done | mysql -u USER -p PASSWORD DBNAME
```

Leave off the `| mysql ...` bit at the end to see the output it prepares for `mysql`.

Comment: I had a little try with `mysql` but proceed with caution and test with a VERY SHORT file in case it is wrong.

Comment: I got the result what I was looking for. But just wanted to know can I get the same information but using for loop?

Comment: I have added how you can do it with a `for` loop at the end. Please have another look.